# Как проверить пользователя по базе?

Tags: c#, база-данных

Создал таблицу в Access, куда с формы заносятся данные (регистрируются пользователи):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\База\V3\database.mdb");
        oleDbConn.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Пользователи (Логин, Пароль, Имя, Фамилия) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "');";
        OleDbCommand oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleDbConn);
        oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        MessageBox.Show("Пользователь успешно зарегистрирован");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Добавил ещё одну таблицу, куда пользователь будет вводить логин и пароль, и соответственно если такие существуют в базе, пускает его в программу, а если нет, то указывает, что он ввёл не существующие данные. Подскажите, как правильно осуществить проверку в базе о зарегистрированных пользователях, спасибо.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (//?)
    {
        //?
        //Открываю форму с основной программой
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Проверьте внесенные данные");
}
```

Comment: У вас есть таблица с пользователями и паролями, у вас есть форма логина где пользователь вводит логин и пароль, у вас есть код работы с БД. В чем проблема проверить при логине юзера, есть ли в БД указанный юзер с указанным паролем?

Comment: Недавно начал разбираться во всей этой теме, поэтому и спрашиваю. Что это так должно работать я понимаю, хочу понять, как реализовать в коде.

Comment: Это очень хорошо, что вы разбираетесь и учитесь. Я потому вам и написал, что делать. Но вообще хранить пароли в базе - плохая практика (обычно хранят хеши паролей), но для учебного проекта сойдет.

Comment: Спасибо, учту в дальнейшем! Сейчас просто хочу разобраться во взаимодействии БД и приложения на c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с хранилищем данных код лучше выносить в отдельный класс.

Передавать параметры лучше через `Parameters`, это защищает от атак типа SQL Injection.

Нужно всегда закрывать все объекты, которые реализуют интерфейс IDisposable, если они больше не нужны. В нашем случае это `OleDbConnection` и `OleDbCommand`.

```
public static class DataProvider
{
    static string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\База\V3\database.mdb";

    public static void InsertUser(string login, string password, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        using (var oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            oleDbConn.Open();
            var sql = "INSERT INTO Пользователи (Логин, Пароль, Имя, Фамилия) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            using (var oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleDbConn))
            {
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@Login", login);
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);

                oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool UserExists(string login, string password)
    {
        using (var oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            oleDbConn.Open();
            var sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Пользователи WHERE Логин = ? AND Пароль = ?";
            using (var oleComm = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleDbConn))
            {
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@Login", login);
                oleComm.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                var result = oleComm.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
                return result == 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляем удобные обертки

```
public static class OleDbExtensions
{
    public static OleDbParameter AddWithValue(this OleDbCommand command, string name, object value)
    {
        return command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter { ParameterName = name, Value = value });
    }
}
```

Что можно улучшить еще?

Убрать `ConnectionString` в app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Main" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Desktop\База\V3\database.mdb" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Немного изменяем наш класс

```
using System.Configuration; // добавить сборку System.Configuration.dll

public static class DataProvider
{
    static string ConnectionString = "";

    static DataProvider()
    {
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ConnectionString
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: Закрытия коннекшина не хватает. Или using добавьте.

Answer (score 2):

По сути в комментарии вам все правильно сказали. Для этого у вас есть форма аутентификации.

Далее, вы делаете `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` параметоризированных запрос к базе вида:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Логин=@Login and Пароль=@Password
```

Параметоризированный запрос очень важен, так как позволяет избежать SQL-инъекции, которая может дать злоумышленнику прочитать то, что он не должен читать.

Если запрос вернул кол-во >0, то пользователь есть в базе и даете ему работать с приложением дальше, в противном случае даете ему работать дальше.